# GSAP Draggable with react ES6 actual this

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, gsap

Im using `gsap` Draggable with `reactjs` `ES6`, I create new draggable like this in react component `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Draggable from 'gsap/Draggable'

class DraggableContainer extends Component {

    render(){
        ...
    }
    componentDidUpdate(){
        const draggable = Draggable.create('.box', {
            onPress: ()=>{
                // currentElement suppost to contain dom element of clicked, but its undefined because 'this' is 'DraggableContainer'
                const currentElement = this.target

            }   
        })
    }
}
```

inside method body of `onPress` this.target should give current element but its undefined and `this` is wrong context.

How can i access current elent inside this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `arrow function`, it will automatically `bind` the context of that `object` which will call that method. To access the target element use `event object`.

> In JavaScript, the thing called this, is the object that "owns" the
>   JavaScript code. The value of this, when used in a function, is the object that "owns" the function.

Write it like this to access the target element:

```
const draggable = Dragable.create('.box', {
   ...,
   onPress:(e) => {
     //now this.target is wrong
     const el = e.target;
   }
})
```

Check this answer for more details about **[this keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)**.